# Unable to resolve base class service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

When trying to activate a `Controller` I get the following error due to a service not properly injected:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
>   'AnubisServer.Server.IDroneOperations' while attempting to activate
>   'AnubisServer.DroneController'.'

I have the following hierachy:

```cs
public interface IOperations { }
public interface ICatalog : IOperations { }
public interface IAdmin : ICatalog { }
public interface ICatalogService : IAdmin, ISomethingElse { }
```

In my startup i am providing a concrete implementation for the most derived interface  `ICatalogService`:

**Startup**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc();
    ICatalogService catalogService = new SomeConcreteService();
    services.AddSingleton(catalogService);
}
```

**Controller**

```cs
public class CatalogController:Controller
{
    private IOperations operations;
    public CatalogController(IOperations ops)
    {
        this.operations=ops;
    }
}
```

So I do not understand why it does not work to inject a base class interface since i am providing a derived concrete instance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `services.AddSingleton<IOperations>(catalogService)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registrations in `IServiceCollection` are key-value pairs, where the service (or abstraction) is the *key* and the component (or implementation) is the value. Lookup will be done based on that exact key. So in your case you *only* registered `ICatalogService`, and *not* `IOperations`. This means the `IOperations` can't be resolved. You will have to register `IOperations` explicitly. For instance:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IOperations>(catalogService);
```

Comment: Well, most framework do provide something like `AsImplementedInterfaces()` (in AutoFac) hence will resolve correctly for the case in question.

Comment: @haim770: You are right about this, but I think the core problem here is OP's understanding of how DI Containers work (with a basic key-value pair dictionary lookup).